# JSON evel() error: missing] after element list

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i'm relatively new to JS and keep getting the error `missing] after element list` when I try and run the following:

Have a JSON file called test.JSON:

```
{
"156644": {
    name: "name1",
    "street": "street1",
    "city": "city1"
},
"68656": {
    "name": "name2 ",
    "street": "street2",
    "city": "city1"
},
"388655": {
    "name": "name3",
    "street": "street3",
    "city": "city1"
},
"4564": {
    "name": "name4",
    "street": "street4",
    "city": "city1"
},
"6333": {
    "name": "name5",
    "street": "street5",
    "city": "city1"
}
 }
```

And some Javascript:

```
var myObject = eval("(" + $.getJSON("test.json") + ")");
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `$.getJSON()` returns what it finds as JSON already, you don't need to eval() it.

Comment: your missing "s arround one of your property names. the first   name : "name1"

Comment: I suspect that test.json is not accessible Please provide a jsFiddle and an attachment with the file. Also fix the quotes around 'name' in first subobject

Answer (score 1):

The `getJSON` function:

1. Will parse JSON into a JavaScript object for you. Don't touch `eval`.
2. Is asynchronous and handles the data via a callback not a return value

So:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", handleData);

function handleData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

You also have a syntax error in your JSON data. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to pinpoint it.